# vb.net check if file being fully copied before moving this file to backup directory

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a video recording software that will record video files in directory. and I am writing vb.net  code to move finished files into another directory ( external hard disk).
I only move files which have been finished recording.

I need only to move files which are finished recording. The problem is my code move files that are still being recorded.
my question : how I can check if a file is not being recorded right now ? 
Thanks

Comment: In similar context I couldn't review the last modified date, but it was quite reliable to use a Timer to periodically review the file length and if it had remained stable for X minutes then I deemed it to have finished. See if dbasnett's answer works out for you and if not I'll dig out the code from my watcher program..

Comment: You could use a FileSystemWatcher. You're usually notified when a file is created and when a File has been closed (it notifies a Size or LastWrite change). Not while a File is being written to, though.

Comment: So, you could use, e.g., a `ConcurrentDictionary(Of string, boolean)` (or a class object instead of a string, to add more details) as storage: when  you receive a File Creation event, pass the file name to a proxy method that adds the file name to the Dictionary if it's not there or sets the corresponding Value to `true` if it is and make the proxy (after a small delay) run a Task that copies a file when it's ready.

Comment: You could attempt to open the file with sharing set to [None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netcore-3.1).  If it fails, then the video recording program still has the file open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code you'll know best how long since the file was written indicates finished.

```
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(dirPath)
    Dim noMod As New TimeSpan(0, 2, 0) 'last write time
    Dim _movTM As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Add(-noMod)

    For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In di.GetFiles
        If fi.LastWriteTime < _movTM Then
            'move here
        End If
    Next
```